# View in navbar to detect clicks

Tags: appcelerator

I am developing an iOS app using Appcelerator. I need to place a transparent view over the window title to be able to click on it.

I am using this code:

```
// Create the view

var titleView = Ti.UI.createView({

width:210,
height:40,
backgroundColor: 'transparent'

});

// Add the view to the title

win.titleControl = titleView;
```

It works fine but the title does not shine through.
What can I do? Do I really need to add a label too?

Thankful for all input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you need to add a label.

once you set the titleControl to the titleView, you have lost the text that use to appear

Comment: Is there another way? It is hard to set a label that looks exactly like the native title.